# .htaccess doesn't work on rewrite rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've looked everywhere but I didn't find nothing works with my case.

My situation is:
I've these paths:

```
https://mysite.it/template/public/show.php?page=tutorSchool&action=4
https://mysite.it/template/public/show.php?page=tutorFactory&action=5
```

etc..

With my .htaccess they results in these on my url bar:

```
https://mysite.it/show.php?page=tutorSchool&action=4
https://mysite.it/show.php?page=tutorFactory&action=5
```

etc..

What I need is this:

```
https://mysite.it/School/some-text-that-i-choosed-for-school-action-4
https://mysite.it/Factory/some-text-that-i-choosed-for-factory-action-5
```

Here you are my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite.it$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/board
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/forum
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/fad
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/template/*

RewriteRule !^template/public/ /template/public%{REQUEST_URI}  [L]
```

I've tried everything I found around, but nothing works and It's driving me crazy.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, so this is my first question here. Someone gave me -1 without explain why... If I made mistakes please tell me where and I'll try to fix the question.

Comment: Try this out to see which of your rules are matching and which aren't http://htaccess.mwl.be/

Comment: "It is driving me crazy" is not very good question summary.

Comment: Ok, I'll change it, but it's the true :)

Comment: @mkaatman I've already tried that site, and the problem is that I was not able to create a new rewrite rule that matching with my situation, to change that "show.php?page=tutorSchool" with something else...